# Microsoft SQL Server Management 2012 and Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

My RDMS is the above. I have a stored procedure that takes 13 parameters. I have a table that holds those input values. I am pasting what I have done. Please help because its not executing. I am getting the following error: Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Please look at the attachment to see the location of the table I am trying to use.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HoWC.png)

```
use ssisconfiguration.dbo.BalladHealthDayOneStats;
exec Clarity.ssis.sp_BalladDayOneMaster
[StatisticStartDate],[StatisticEndDate],[CostCenterList],[ProcedureCodeList],[Statistic],[StatisticDescription],[PatientTypeIndicator],
--[RVThreshold],[FiscalYear],
1,2017,
[PatientServiceList],[PatientClassList],[PatientStatusList]
```

Comment: You seem to be using `USE` incorrectly... `USE` is for using a database, not a table. So really, if you want to use the database ssisconfiguration, it would just be `use ssisconfiguration;`. But your query is running in the clarity database, so really you should be doing `USE Clarity; EXEC ssis.sp_BalladDayOneMaster ...` Also your query isn't going to run anyway because your parameters aren't being supplied by anything (e.g. what is `[StatisticsStartDate]` and where does it come from?)

Comment: Right, so I just realised you want to use the columns from the table `BalladHealthDayOneStats` to supply the parameters for that stored procedure. In that case, I _believe_ you want something like in this link: http://rextester.com/IZBXH17495 (essentially, you need to put the columns into variables and execute the procedure that way).

Comment: @ZLK Thank you VERY VERY much! I am attaching the results. It now runs cleanly but I don't get any output. I also attached whats in the table I am reading in. If you can, can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? I did add a few things, so maybe that's it? I couldn't figure out how to add attachments to this comment so I added it to the main.

Comment: I did not get it added, I don't know how. I used what you sent me but added EXEC @RCout = Clarity.ssis.sp_BalladDayOneMaster. Since the tables the sp reads is in the clarity db, but the table I am reading the parm values from is in ssisconfiguration, is that my issue?

Comment: You would need to show what the procedure is doing and what the inputs are. What happens if you just run the procedure with static input (test values)?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of USE is to select the database.
i would suggest modify to

```
use ssisconfiguration
exec Clarity.ssis.sp_BalladDayOneMaster
([StatisticStartDate],[StatisticEndDate],[CostCenterList],[ProcedureCodeList],[Statistic],[StatisticDescription],[PatientTypeIndicator],
--[RVThreshold],[FiscalYear],
1,2017,
[PatientServiceList],[PatientClassList],[PatientStatusList])
```

replace the column name with values in the []